# How to create reusable code with ember.computed?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am totally new to ember, and after a lot of hours of searching I couldn't figure out how to make reusable code with Ember.computed properties. 
Here is an example: I have two controllers which have similar part of code for sorting arrays(they recieve different models)

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    sortProps: ['createdAt:desc'],
    sortedPosts: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProps'),
    last3SortedPosts: Ember.computed('sortedPosts', function() {
    return this.get('sortedPosts').slice(0,3);
}),

...
```

and I wish not to write it twice. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **mixins/sorted-posts.js**

```
export default Ember.Mixin.extend({
  sortProps: ['createdAt:desc'],
  sortedPosts: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProps'),
  last3SortedPosts: Ember.computed('sortedPosts', function() {
    return this.get('sortedPosts').slice(0,3);
  })
});
```

In your controller:

```
import SortedPostsMixin from '../mixins/sorted-posts';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(SortedPostsMixin, {
/* .. */
});
```